# Javascript array join() and getelementbyid error

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javaScript and i'm having quite some troubles with it.. The general idea behind this program is that the user enters some values in the 6 text boxes and after submitting, those are shown concatecated in the text result box. But so far no value comes in the text box and I dont know what the error is... Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function concatetext(array)
        {
            var n = new Array[];
            for (var i=0; i<f['array[]'].length; ++i)
            {
                n[x] = document.forms["form1"].elements["array" + x].value;
            }
            document.getElementById('textresult').innerHTML = n.join();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" onsubmit="concatetext(text)">
        text 1:<input type="textbox" name="text[]" size="16 px" />
        <br />
        text 2:<input type="textbox" name="text[]" size="16 px" />
        <br />
        text 3:<input type="textbox" name="text[]" size="16 px" />
        <br />
        text 4:<input type="textbox" name="text[]" size="16 px" />
        <br />
        text 5:<input type="textbox" name="text[]" size="16 px" />
        <br />
        text 6:<input type="textbox" name="text[]" size="16 px" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"  />
        <br /><br />
        text Result:<input type="textbox" id="textresult" size="35 px" />
        <br />

    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use `id` attributes instead of `name` attributes. You'll thank me later.

Comment: @MattMcDonald but id's have to be unique. it's nice to cluster objects by name. Just don't use the same name and id ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "";
$("#form1 input").each(function() {
    text += $(this).val();
});
$("#textresult").val(text);
```

Using [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/)

Using raw javascript :

```
var text = "";
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("text[]");
for (var i = 0, ii = inputs.length; i < ii; i++) {
    text += inputs[i].value;
}
document.getElementById("textresult").value = text;
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/SPXfL/9/)

Comment: Thanks for your input but the problem is still there.. It still doesn't display the results in the text box.

Comment: @user753918 make sure to use `.value = text` and it probably won't work in IE8

Comment: Since when is `querySelectorAll` a useful alternative to `getElementsByTagName`? And since when is there global support for `Array.forEach`?

Comment: @Zirak there is not. I was just being lazy with sugar. We've got IE9/FF4/Chrome we can use ES5/DOM3 now surely :(. IE8 must die.

Answer (score 0):

To set the contents of the `<input>` you don't use "innerHTML", you use "value":

```
document.getElementById("textresult").value = text;
```

Also the "size" attribute should just be "35", or else you can give it a "style" with "width: 35px". The "size" attribute sets the size in "em" units (I think), so if you want 35 pixels use "style" instead.